# Live Ubuntu server install on USB

Tags: server, live-usb

I just got a server with no HDD's and want to run Ubuntu server until my SSD arrives. How would I create a persistent live Ubuntu server USB without installing it from another CD/USB?

Answer (score 0):

www.PenDriveLinux.com offers both the Universal USB Installer (UUI) and YUMI (multiboot tool, similar to UUI). Both are primarily Windows applications, but the site has some guidance on creating the same USB device via Linux.

It writes many popular GNU/Linux (and other) distros to a USB device with a Live boot configuration. Ubuntu support is pretty mature. I am not experienced with running a Live server using it, but I imagine it is possible.

If you have a Linux system, you could also just write the .ISO to the USB via:

`# dd if=ubuntu-server.iso of=/dev/path/to/USB`

although this may not create a usable Live device. I don't know if the Ubuntu devs included Live booting capabilities to the server .ISO (they *did* add it to the desktop .ISO...)